# Magento giving 404 for custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I am trying to create a module for magento. I have placed it in 'local' codepool, 'Sample' namespace, 'Practice' folder . It appears in admin panel but when I type the url I get 404 response.

config.xml

```
 <config>
    <modules>
    <Sample_Practice>
     <version>0.1.0</version>

    </Sample_Practice>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <practice>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Sample_Practice</module>
                    <frontName>practice</frontName>
                </args>
            </practice>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>

    </config>
```

**module config file name is Sample_Practice.xml**

```
   <config>
    <modules>

       <Sample_Practice>

         <active>true</active>
         <codepool>local</codepool>

       </Sample_Practice>

    </modules>

    </config>
```

IndexController.php

```
<?php

   class Sample_Practice_IndexController extends      Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        
   public function indexAction() {
    echo 'Practice module';
   }
 }

?>
```

Where is my code breaking ?

Comment: Are you disable/refresh cache ?

Comment: Yes, my cache is disabled.

Comment: have you added IndexController.php  ad location \app\code\local\Sample\Practice\controllers?

Comment: Yes, I have added it in controllers folder. @Abdul

Comment: What URL are you accessing that is showing 404?

Comment: base_url/index.php/practice  @JonathanHussey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issue in your modules:

- `codepool` should be `codePool` in  module config file `Sample_Practice.xml` .Means **P** should be  in `capital letter`

*This magento 1.X methodology*

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your code from**

```
<config>
    <modules>

       <Sample_Practice>

         <active>true</active>
         <codepool>local</codepool>

       </Sample_Practice>

    </modules>

    </config>
```

**To**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sample_Practice>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sample_Practice>
    </modules>
</config>
```